# How to change Virtual Directory Local Path for a MOSS WebApp?

Tags: moss, sharepoint-2007

I have a MOSS web site with its virtual directory in IIS.
That VD maps to a folder in certain location in the C: disk.

I need to move that folder to the same location but in the D: disk.

If it were a common web app it is no problem, just change the "Local Path".
But as it is a MOSS website... I think that this will break that MOSS website.

**Any tip on how to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mattjimison.com/blog/2009/02/26/how-to-change-the-iis-path-for-a-sharepoint-web-application/) is shown how to update the SharePoint web application after you changed the physical path.

This way you can even move your central administration to another folder (like I did).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do a backup, from within the Central Administration, of both the database on web application. Create a new web application on the new virtual directory path and restore the application there.

You can change the default virtual directory path in the Create New Web Applicaion window.

It is also a good practise to change the default virtual path in IIs to point it to another drive than the system drive.